# FATAL EXCEPTION onItemClick Listener

Tags: java, android, onitemclicklistener

The situation is when I select one of the list item. It will show the details of the item on the next activity.

I trying to getting a values from selected `ListItem` by using `onItemClick` Listener. I got `error [FATAL EXCEPTION]`  while click on the item.

Please help me.

This is part of ScheduleFragment.java

```
public class ScheduleFragment extends Fragment {
 /* other activity */

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_schedule, container, false);

myListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);

    // on selecting single subject
    myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String matrix_id = ((ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list)).getText()
                    .toString();

            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                    SingleSubject.class);

            // sending matrix id to next activity
            in.putExtra(TAG_MATRIX_ID, matrix_id);

            // starting new activity and expecting some response back
            startActivityForResult(in, 100);
        }
    });
```

This is SingleSubject.java

```
public class SingleSubject extends Activity {

    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.single_subject);


    // getting subject details from intent
    Intent i = getIntent();

    // getting matrix_id from intent
    matrix_id = i.getStringExtra(TAG_MATRIX_ID);

    // Getting complete matrix_id details in background thread
    new GetSubjectDetails().execute();


}
```

This single_subject.xml

```
<!-- Name Label -->
<TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Name"
    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
    android:paddingRight="10dip"
    android:paddingTop="10dip"
    android:textSize="17dip"/>

<!-- Input Name -->
<EditText android:id="@+id/inputName"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
    android:singleLine="true"/>

<!-- Email Label -->
<TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Email"
    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
    android:paddingRight="10dip"
    android:paddingTop="10dip"
    android:textSize="17dip"/>

<!-- Input Email -->
<EditText android:id="@+id/inputEmail" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
    android:singleLine="true"/>
```

This is fragment_schedule.xml

```
 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

This is log error.

```
03-25 14:40:49.808: W/dalvikvm(10182): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40d09930)
03-25 14:40:49.854: E/AndroidRuntime(10182): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-25 14:40:49.854: E/AndroidRuntime(10182): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-25 14:40:49.854: E/AndroidRuntime(10182):    at com.ultra.esc.ScheduleFragment$1.onItemClick(ScheduleFragment.java:95)
03-25 14:40:49.854: E/AndroidRuntime(10182):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
03-25 14:40:49.854: E/AndroidRuntime(10182):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)
03-25 14:40:49.854: E/AndroidRuntime(10182):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2749)
03-25 14:40:49.854: E/AndroidRuntime(10182):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3423)
03-25 14:40:49.854: E/AndroidRuntime(10182):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
03-25 14:40:49.854: E/AndroidRuntime(10182):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-25 14:40:49.854: E/AndroidRuntime(10182):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-25 14:40:49.854: E/AndroidRuntime(10182):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
03-25 14:40:49.854: E/AndroidRuntime(10182):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-25 14:40:49.854: E/AndroidRuntime(10182):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-25 14:40:49.854: E/AndroidRuntime(10182):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-25 14:40:49.854: E/AndroidRuntime(10182):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-25 14:40:49.854: E/AndroidRuntime(10182):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: show your adapter code

Comment: post your getView method..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have a listview in the layout that you inflate for the adapter

```
 String matrix_id = ((ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list)).getText()
                .toString();
```

Hence the above initialization gives you `NullpointerExcpetion`.

Guess work:

I can guess from the previous question that i answered of yours ([ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22625502/classcastexception-android-widget-textview-cannot-be-cast-to-android-widget-lis/22625526#22625526)). You have TextView's for the layout that you inflate in your adapter with ids `R.id.matrix_id` and  `R.id.name`. But to confirm you can post your adapter code.

Copying from your previous question

```
 ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                       getActivity(), subjectList,
                    R.layout.all_subject, new String[] { TAG_MATRIX_ID,
                            TAG_NAME},
                    new int[] { R.id.matrix_id, R.id.name });
```

You can use `getTag` and `setTag` to avoid initialization of views again as suggested by laalto or

```
 String matrix_id = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.matrix_id)).getText()
                .toString();

 String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText()
                .toString();
```

Comment: yeah that's true the adapter id is R.id.matrix_id and R.id.name

Comment: @ultra_buckner then you need to change as suggested in my post

Comment: I think we have misunderstanding at here. I have edited my question. I want to bring the value of matrix_id using intent to the SingleSubject.java

Comment: @ultra_buckner you have misunderstood my post. Not me Post the adapter code

Comment: @ultra_buckner just have those 2 lines in your `onItemClick` and i will work

Comment: I need to bring the value of matrix_id to the SingleSubject.java via intent. Is that necessary to bring the value of name together ?

I have run your code but its Error on android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Comment: @ultra_buckner if you just want the `matrix_id` there is no need for the name. `NetworkOnMainThreadException` occurs when you run network operation on the main ui thread.

Comment: I taught that only [extends fragment] can cause that. But its still happen on [extends activity].

Comment: @ultra_buckner it happens when you run network operation on ui thread. Now do you understand what ui thread means? forget what you extend

Comment: to interact with component of Android UI tools

Comment: @ultra_buckne does not matter what you extend its still the ui thread. Use a `Thread` or `Asynctask`. For further info read the docs

Comment: Can I ask you something sir ?

Comment: @ultra_buckner post a different question if you have a different problem. Comment is not the place for discussion

Comment: oh, sorry sir, my mistake

Comment: sir please check my [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22633470/how-to-check-whether-the-class-being-execute-or-not?noredirect=1#comment34468598_22633470)
need your supervision

Answer (score 0):

The item that was clicked is a child of the listview. You don't find the listview by looking at the children of the item here:

```
String matrix_id = ((ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list)).getText()
                .toString();
```

One way to pass ids around is to `setTag()` the views in adapter `getView()` and call `getTag()` to retrieve it.