# How to check whether the class being execute or not

Tags: java, android

I want to check whether the class being execute or not. Because it didnt give any value on inputName and inputEmail. The value is retrieve from the database.

This is part of the code (SingleSubject.java)

```
public class SingleSubject extends Activity {

EditText txtName;
EditText txtEmail;

String matrix_id;

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// JSON parser class
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

// single product url
private static final String url_subject_details = "http://192.168.1.12/android_project/get_subject_details.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_STUDENT = "student";

private static final String TAG_MATRIX_ID = "matrix_id";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "email";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.single_subject);


    // getting subject details from intent
    Intent i = getIntent();

    // getting matrix_id from intent
    matrix_id = i.getStringExtra(TAG_MATRIX_ID);
    TextView test = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.matrix_id);
    test.setText(matrix_id);

    // Getting complete matrix_id details in background thread
    new GetSubjectDetails().execute();


}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Get complete matrix_id details
 * */
class GetSubjectDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(SingleSubject.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading subject details. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }


    /**
     * Getting subject details in background thread
     * */
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

        JSONObject json = null;

        try {
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("matrix_id", matrix_id));
                json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_subject_details, "GET", params);

            }

        catch(Exception e)
            {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }   
        return json;

    }


    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
        super.onPostExecute(json);

        // check your log for json response
        Log.d("Single Subject Details", json.toString());

        // json success tag
        success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

        if (success.equals(1)) {
            // successfully received subject details
            JSONArray subjectObj = json.getJSONArray(TAG_STUDENT); // JSON Array

            // get first subject object from JSON Array
            JSONObject subject = subjectObj.getJSONObject(0);

        // subject with this matrix_id found
        // Edit Text
        txtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
        txtEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputEmail);

        // display subject data in EditText
        txtName.setText(subject.getString(TAG_NAME));
        txtEmail.setText(subject.getString(TAG_EMAIL));         

        }
        // dismiss the dialog once got all details      
        pDialog.dismiss();


    }
}

  }
```

Comment: sry but why are you starting a thread in doInBackground? This makes no sense...

Comment: And you can not Update UI Elements such as EditText from the Thread, make all UIStuff in onPosteExecute ad pass it the result of your doInBackground

Comment: there is not need to create a thread inside an AsyncTask. The doInBackground method does everything asynchronously.

Comment: Please have a look at Android Tutorials how to use ASynctask, this looks to me lika copy and paste and no understanding....

Comment: @A.S. this is part of the code man

Comment: @A.S. I have edited with the full code.

Comment: @ultra_buckner `doInbackground` is invoked on the ui thread. No need for a thread there

Comment: so you have edited but not followed my tips.

Comment: @A.S. sory sir, but im not very clear on that.

Comment: @ultra_buckner stop commenting post a new question with relevant details if its deemed fit by the community the question stays else it is closed. New problem new question

Comment: @ultra_buckner `success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);` where is sucess declared?. If you keep editing your my answer to the origina; post has no value. So new problem new question. Pls don't edit your question so that it looks completely different.

Comment: im sory sir, should i re-edit my post to the original ?

Comment: u have downvote me, im really sorry for my mistake. but can u help me for the last sir ?

Comment: @ultra_buckner how do you i downvoted. i already pointed you that you haven't declared the variable `success`. There is certain limit on the number of edit of each post. Beyond which it becomes community wiki. To compare int use  `int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);if (success==1)) {`.  If you are new to the site pls read the FAQ's before you ask a new question or comment again.This is my last comment. Good luck

Comment: glad and nice to meet you, even though its for a while, its ok:) Perhaps I can help you one day. Best Regards sir Raghunandan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`doInbackground` is invoked on the background thread. No need to create a thread there

```
txtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
txtEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputEmail);
txtName.setText(subject.getString(TAG_NAME)); // updating ui not possible in doInbackground
txtEmail.setText(subject.getString(TAG_EMAIL));
```

Secondly you cannot update ui from a background thread. You need to update ui in `onPostExecute` .You can return result in `doInbackground` which is param to `onPostExecute` and update ui there.

You need to look at the docs of `AsyncTask` to understand more

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Edit:

Change this

```
 class GetSubjectDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
```

to

```
 class GetSubjectDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONOBject> {
```

Then

```
 protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {

            JSONObject json =null;            
            try {
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("matrix_id", matrix_id));
                json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                        url_subject_details, "GET", params);
                }catch(Exception e)
                {
                  e.printStacktrace();
                }   
    return json;
  }
```

Then

```
 @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
    super.onPostExecute(json);
    pDialog.dismiss();
    // parse json
    // update ui  
}
```

Comment: sir,
how I want to declare a variable of JSONObject ?
should I declare it to private ?

Comment: @ultra_buckner better read the docs first or else you end up in ore confusion. Study declaring variables in java first.

Comment: @ultra_buckner do check the edit. rest is upto you. But be sure to read the docs or you end up in more confusions

Comment: Im sory sir, but how to create a variable for json success tag.
I have read the docs and it says that it is invalid for create a return value in onPostExecute, is it true ?

Comment: @ultra_buckner where does the return come from. the docs certainly does not say anything about it. `protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {` the return type is void. And what variable ar you talking about

Comment: @ultra_buckner first of all you need to parse the json. Right now i posted code and gave you a indication of where to put the code and where to update ui. Now if you ask me "how to create a variable for json succees tag" then you should really learn java first.

Comment: Im not read from your link docs master, I read the other docs, Im sory, 

This variable `success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);`

Im really sorry for interrupting you. Im sorry

Comment: @ultra_buckner which docs did you refer. Can you link me to it. The official docs is the link i posted. Secondly this is parsing json `success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS)` Now what has parsing gotta do with creating a variable??

Comment: Its ok, I will learn Java. Thank you for your concern. Best Regards

Comment: @ultra_buckner you need this  `int value = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS)` in `onPostExecute`. I don't now what variable you want other than that. I really confused as to what you want

Comment: what I mean is, when I put the `success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS)` in the `onPostExecute` its return error.

Comment: @ultra_buckner post a new question with the full code and pls ask a question clearly. This is parsing  problem not variable or anything else

Comment: master, please help me on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22638674/failed-to-update-ui-in-onpostexecute?noredirect=1#comment34478711_22638674)