# How to set TextView by XML

Tags: android, textview

When I run the apps, there show a error on `list.setAdapter(newsAdapter);`
How can I solve it?

XML code as follows:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/NewsTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/gray"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="@dimen/topicsize" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Java as follows:

```
public class Fragment_NewsContent extends Fragment {
ArrayAdapter<String> newsAdapter;
ArrayList<String> newsTitle = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_newscontent, container, false);
    TextView list = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.NewsTitle);
    newsAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, newsTitle);
    list.setAdapter(newsAdapter);
    showNewsTask task=new showNewsTask();
    task.execute();
    return root;
    }

class showNewsTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://garyhui86.er-webs.com/newxContent.xml");
            HttpURLConnection urlConn = 
                                 (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            if (urlConn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory
                        .newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
                Document document = builder.parse(urlConn.getInputStream());
                NodeList nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("Info");
                for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
                    NamedNodeMap attributes=nodeList.item(i).getAttributes();
                    String category=attributes.getNamedItem("NewsTitle").getNodeValue();
                    Log.i("ttt", category);
                    newsTitle.add(category);
                }
            }
            urlConn.disconnect();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        newsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: if i change the TextView into ListView
it case some error as follow

04-27 19:34:15.278: E/AndroidRuntime(13131):<br/>java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.ListView

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cast a **TextView** to a **ListView** as they are different animals entirely. 

Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22625502/classcastexception-android-widget-textview-cannot-be-cast-to-android-widget-lis) for an example of this.